# Executor service not waiting until all threads get completed to return the result

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, countdownlatch

I am using an Executor service to execute set of parallel tasks and I need one done something after all the tasks get completed. But in my below implementation it is not happening as expected and it is not waiting till all done. Please refer to the code snippet below.

```
public void doParallelStuff() throws InterruptedException {
        
        final int THREAD_COUNT = 5;
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);
        Set<String> myIdSet = Set.of("123", "234", "345", "897", "893"); // actual set is having 20k+ IDs
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(myIdSet.size());

        myIdSet.forEach(id -> executorService.execute(() -> {
            // retrieve & do processing the entity related to id
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }));

        countDownLatch.await(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        executorService.shutdown();

        // do some other stuff after all completed
        // (but this point is getting executed before the all tasks get completed)
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing that it takes longer than ten seconds for all the threads to complete. Did you try calling [await()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#await()) instead of `await(long,TimeUnit)` ? Alternatively, did you try increasing the timeout period to more than ten seconds?

Comment: If you have 20,000 threads, running 5 at a time, and (for example) each thread takes 10ms, then you're looking at 10*20000/5=40,000ms or 40 seconds elapsed. This is just ballpark, but gives a sense of what you can expect. To meet your "10 second" timeout, and keeping 20,000 threads and threadpool of 5, you would need each thread to complete in ~2ms (or less). How long do you expect each thread to take? Is 2ms realistic?

Comment: Also, go ahead and leave the await(10) in there, and try adding something like this just after that line: `System.out.println("latch count: " + countDownLatch.getCount())`. That will show you real-world performance of the whole thing; you can determine how many threads ran to completion in 10 seconds.

Comment: Oh.. understood, but it will vary depend on the environment. So any possible way to tackle all? May be `await()`?

Comment: It depends what you're solving for. If you need to run all threads regardless of duration, then yeah use `await()` (without a timeout). Instead, if you have a time limit that's more important than "run all to completion", then set a timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Lose the `CountDownLatch`

You don't need the `CountDownLatch`. An executor service provides that feature, built-in.

## `shutdown` & `awaitTermination` in `ExecutorService`

The key is making two calls:

- `ExecutorService#shutdown` to stop the executor service from accepting more task submissions.
- `ExecutorService#awaitTermination` to block and wait for all submitted tasks to finish.

Here is the main chunk of code excerpted from a full example app posted further down.

First we generate some fake input. And we define a thread-safe list to hold `Result` objects, with each submitted task instantiated and collecting a fresh `Result` object.

```java
Set < Integer > ids = IntStream.range( 1 , 20_001 ).boxed().collect( Collectors.toSet() );
List < Result > results = Collections.synchronizedList( new ArrayList <>() );
```

Next we define a collection to hold our pending tasks. We populate with many `Task` objects.

```java
List < Task > tasks = new ArrayList <>( ids.size() );
for ( Integer id : ids ) tasks.add( new Task( id , results ) );
```

We create an executor service with a reasonable number of threads, as appropriate to our deployment machine.

```java
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 7 );
```

Next we define a collection to keep all the `Future` objects returned by the executor service when we submit all our tasks.

```java
List < Future < Boolean > > futures = null;
```

Submit all the tasks, capturing the futures.

```java
try { futures = executorService.invokeAll( tasks , 5 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
```

Make those two crucial calls in this subroutine, to invoke a shutdown and wait for tasks to complete.

```java
this.shutdownAndAwaitTermination( executorService );  // Blocks here, until either (a) executor service completes all assigned tasks, or (b) time-out fires.
```

The key concept is that the code above blocks until all submitted tasks are done… or until the specified time-out fires.

Lastly, we can report on the work.

```java
this.report( futures , results );
```

### Complete code example

```java
package work.basil.example.parallel;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    record Result( Integer id , UUID label , Instant whenCreated ) { }

    class Task implements Callable < Boolean >
    {
        private Integer id;
        private List < Result > results;

        public Task ( Integer id , List < Result > results )
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.results = results;
        }

        @Override
        public Boolean call ( )
        {
            try { Thread.sleep( ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 0 , 5 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }  // Pretend this method takes a while to do its work.
            Result result = new Result( this.id , UUID.randomUUID() , Instant.now() );
            this.results.add( result );
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        }
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - Demo starting. " + Instant.now() );

        Set < Integer > ids = IntStream.range( 1 , 20_001 ).boxed().collect( Collectors.toSet() );
        List < Result > results = Collections.synchronizedList( new ArrayList <>() );

        List < Task > tasks = new ArrayList <>( ids.size() );
        for ( Integer id : ids ) tasks.add( new Task( id , results ) );

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 7 );
        List < Future < Boolean > > futures = null;
        try { futures = executorService.invokeAll( tasks , 5 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
        this.shutdownAndAwaitTermination( executorService );  // Blocks here, until either (a) executor service completes all assigned tasks, or (b) time-out fires.
        this.report( futures , results );

        System.out.println( "INFO - Demo ending. " + Instant.now() );
    }

    private void report ( final List < Future < Boolean > > futures , final List < Result > results )
    {
        List < Future < Boolean > > failedFutures =
                futures.stream().filter( future -> {
                            try { return future.isCancelled() || ! future.isDone() || Objects.isNull( future.get() ) || Objects.equals( future.get() , Boolean.FALSE ); }
                            catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
                            catch ( ExecutionException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
                        } )
                        .toList();
        System.out.println( failedFutures.size() + " failed futures:\n" + failedFutures );

        List < Future < Boolean > > doneFutures = futures.stream().filter( future -> {
            try { return future.isDone() && future.get().equals( Boolean.TRUE ); }
            catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
            catch ( ExecutionException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
        } ).toList();
        System.out.println( doneFutures.size() + " done futures." );

        System.out.println( "First 10 results: " );
        results.stream().limit( 10 ).forEach( System.out :: println );
    }

    // Boilerplate taken from Javadoc of `ExecutorService`, and slightly edited.
    private void shutdownAndAwaitTermination ( ExecutorService executorService )
    {
        executorService.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
        try
        {
            // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
            if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination( 5 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ) )
            {
                executorService.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
                // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
                if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination( 5 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ) )
                { System.err.println( "Executor service failed to terminate." ); }
            }
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException ex )
        {
            executorService.shutdownNow();       // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();           // Preserve interrupt status
        }
    }
}
```

When run:

```
INFO - Demo starting. 2022-07-22T06:23:19.725428Z
0 failed futures:
[]
20000 done futures.
First 10 results: 
Result[id=7, label=609c5f42-3108-4ed7-a92d-0485016238c7, whenCreated=2022-07-22T06:23:19.765087Z]
Result[id=2, label=5dad4f85-e572-4a06-b226-f402fd3295c3, whenCreated=2022-07-22T06:23:19.765101Z]
Result[id=6, label=97d1786a-830b-42e5-97bb-48e6342fe3b1, whenCreated=2022-07-22T06:23:19.765140Z]
Result[id=4, label=17ae84ac-0dd8-477a-8b67-d4770643a015, whenCreated=2022-07-22T06:23:19.765191Z]
Result[id=5, label=55d4f4ba-9f5d-42f0-9af6-9e6c53159ce9, whenCreated=2022-07-22T06:23:19.765220Z]
Result[id=1, label=2d55c303-8366-441d-a62b-3168158329e0, whenCreated=2022-07-22T06:23:19.765261Z]
Result[id=3, label=ad4c7d04-7917-432e-8ad5-b0312b03d1bd, whenCreated=2022-07-22T06:23:19.765292Z]
Result[id=9, label=2774d965-f179-4b5b-a50f-361f5e4a1a08, whenCreated=2022-07-22T06:23:19.765346Z]
Result[id=13, label=54f48070-2967-4307-b4f9-80d34ece5332, whenCreated=2022-07-22T06:23:19.765378Z]
Result[id=11, label=00899822-591e-4af2-8b32-d496c3997e65, whenCreated=2022-07-22T06:23:19.766582Z]
INFO - Demo ending. 2022-07-22T06:23:27.027545Z
```

### Parallel Streams

Using parallel streams may be a simpler route, depending on your specific needs. You have less control, such as not specifying the number of threads (by default), and less flexibility in the face of failures. But you get drastically shorter simpler code.

Define a record to hold each result. This is similar to above, but here we use  a `String` type for `id` to be closer to your original Question.

```java
record Result( String id , UUID label , Instant whenCreated ) { }
```

Create some bogus input data, as strings.

```java
List < String > ids =
        IntStream
                .range( 1 , 20_001 )
                .boxed()
                .map( Object :: toString )
                .toUnmodifiableList();
```

And do the work, all in a single line of code. The `.parallelStream` automatically handles getting a pool of threads of a reasonable size, and then doing the work of instantiating our `Result` object as tasks assigned to the various threads.

```java
List < Result > results =
        ids
                .parallelStream()
                .map( ( String id ) -> new Result( id , UUID.randomUUID() , Instant.now() ) )
                .toUnmodifiableList();
```

Lastly, report results.

```java
results.stream().limit( 10 ).forEach( System.out :: println );
```

Be aware that using parallel streams only makes sense where you have a lengthy workload. For a brief workload, using parallel streams rather than single stream may actually take *more* time, as there is overhead in setting up, managing, and collecting results across threads.

## *Project Loom*

Everything above is relevant for today's Java. If [*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/loom/Main) succeeds, and it looks like it will, the rules of the game will be changed… for the better.

To learn more, see posts, interviews, and presentations by members of the Loom team such as Ron Pressler and Alan Bateman. Focus on the more recent info, as Loom has evolved over time. And see the Java JEPs for [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/425), and for [structured concurrency](https://openjdk.org/jeps/428). Previews are found in Java 19.

Comment: This is a precious lesson more than an answer to me. Learnt a lot from this and thank you so much for the time you dedicated for this. Thanks a lot again!!! :-) <3